# How do I access the currently logged in user from new controllers I create?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my problem.  I'm building a web application using MVC3 framework.  My application started as the sample website included in the MVC3 Installation.

That web application was already setup for users to be able to login.

My problem is this.

I need to save files when the user logs in, I need the files to be created under folders named after the `UserName`

How do I access the Logged in users info and profile?  When I evaluate `HttpContext.Current.User` It returns my windows NTLM logon name, not the name i logged into the site with.  Here is what my web.config looks like.

```
<profile defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProfileProvider"  enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />         
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name ="TaxPayerID" type="String"/>
  </properties>
</profile>


<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had removed the authentication section of my web.config file. I realized that right after I posted this

Answer (score 1):

Your custom controller should inherit from the base `Controller` class. Access the logged in user via:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: I had removed the authentication section of my web.config file.  I realized that right after I posted this question.

Comment: yes, I can't delete the question though. I guess all flag it.